# Facebook not reading OG Tags

Tags: facebook-opengraph, blogs, sharing

This had been an on and off problem for some time and i have run out of ideas now. Last week all of my blog posts shared correctly. Now when sharing no image preview is generated. When i run the posts through facebook debugger it tells me

Inferred Property
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Missing Properties
The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id

But when you look at the source code the Tags are there and i can't see any duplicate tags which caused me problems in the past. I've included 2 examples, one with the height and width tags added as someone told me that should help but didn't make a difference.

view-source:https://www.scrapingsolutions.com.au/how-to-capture-linkedin-leads-the-new-way-vs-the-old-way/

view-source:https://www.industrycompete.com.au/how-to-capture-linkedin-leads-the-new-way-vs-the-old-way/

If anyone has a solution i would love to hear it! Thanks!

``````
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Scraping Solutions" />
<meta property="og:title" content="How To Capture LinkedIn Leads: The New Way vs. The Old Way" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.scrapingsolutions.com.au/how-to-capture-linkedin-leads-the-new-way-vs-the-old-way/" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:description" content="What is the biggest challenge facing a budding entrepreneur or business owner? Well, most of them struggle to generate good quality leads that can be converted into loyal customers.

No doubt, the advent of the internet in the 90s and subsequent birth of digital marketing has led to the adoption o" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.scrapingsolutions.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/shutterstock_1710441700_ed.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:url" content="https://www.scrapingsolutions.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/shutterstock_1710441700_ed.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://www.scrapingsolutions.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/shutterstock_1710441700_ed.jpg" />
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2020-07-25T12:43:32+00:00" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2020-07-29T03:15:41+00:00" />
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="2020-07-29T03:15:41+00:00" />
<meta property="article:section" content="Digital Marketing" />
<meta property="article:section" content="Email Collector" />
<meta property="article:section" content="Lead Generation" />
<meta property="article:section" content="LinkedIn" />
<meta property="article:section" content="Task Automation" />
<meta property="article:section" content="Tech" />
<meta property="article:section" content="Web Scraping" />

<meta itemprop="name" content="How To Capture LinkedIn Leads: The New Way vs. The Old Way" />
<meta itemprop="headline" content="How To Capture LinkedIn Leads: The New Way vs. The Old Way" />
<meta itemprop="description" content="What is the biggest challenge facing a budding entrepreneur or business owner? Well, most of them struggle to generate good quality leads that can be converted into loyal customers.

No doubt, the advent of the internet in the 90s and subsequent birth of digital marketing has led to the adoption o" />
<meta itemprop="image" content="https://www.scrapingsolutions.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/shutterstock_1710441700_ed.jpg" />
<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2020-07-25" />
<meta itemprop="dateModified" content="2020-07-29T03:15:41+00:00" />
<meta itemprop="author" content="Michael Attwood" />
 

<meta name="twitter:title" content="How To Capture LinkedIn Leads: The New Way vs. The Old Way" />
<meta name="twitter:url" content="https://www.scrapingsolutions.com.au/how-to-capture-linkedin-leads-the-new-way-vs-the-old-way/" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="What is the biggest challenge facing a budding entrepreneur or business owner? Well, most of them struggle to generate good quality leads that can be converted into loyal customers.

No doubt, the advent of the internet in the 90s and subsequent birth of digital marketing has led to the adoption o" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://www.scrapingsolutions.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/shutterstock_1710441700_ed.jpg" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />`````
``````

Comment: This happens to my website s well since this morning. I'm hoping this is a fb issue and not something that i did wrong

Comment: I figured out the problem was related to Cache, when I removed W3TC plugin the problem went away. I still wanted to use the plugin though so tried setting a cache rule on cloudflare and then reinstalled the W3TC plugin and since then its been fine. Just needed to use facebook debugger to rescrape some of the posts. Not sure why this solved the problem but it worked for me.